# Redirect http to https except a file.php or the url

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

I had 2 sites and both installed ssl;

The hosting told me to put this code on each .htaccess to force https.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$ 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I need some pages to be viewed as http because its related to view other site which is http inside frame.

For the first site;
`https://www.example.com/index.php?view=click&`

or 
when I logged in to the site the url look like this;

`https://www.example.com/index.php?view=click&sid=10T1M0MU1qRXpPRFkyTU&sid2=10T1M&siduid=10&`

The file was click.php located at `example.com/members/click.php`

For the second site:
`https://www.example.com/abc.php`
And
`https://www.example.com/abc1.php`

I searched all questions that related to redirect https to http, tried some and failed. I really need help :)
Thank you

Comment: So you want to **exclude** all URIs that end with `.php` ?

Comment: I dont know for the first site, the url is different. For the second site, yes